# Abelian Groups properties in finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How we can see if a group is abelain then every element has its own inverse? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I could'nt follow. I have ab=ba I need to show a^2=1?

Comment: In a general abelian group, not every element is its own inverse; for example, for $1\in\Bbb Z/(4)$ we have $1 + 1 = 2\neq 0$. In a general group, every element $g$ has a corresponding $g^{-1}$ such that $g g^{-1} = g^{-1} g = e$, so if that is what you meant, this is true of all groups by definition, not just abelian ones. Do you mean to ask that if every element is its own inverse, is the group abelian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean every element has an inverse, that's an inherent property of groups, they don't need to be abelian.

If you mean is its own inverse, consider $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ under addition.  $1+1=2\neq e=0$, so $1$ is not its own inverse, but $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is an abelian group.

However, every group where every element is its own inverse, that is every element has order two or one, is abelian.  That might be the question you're after, in which case the proof is as follows:

If $g,h\in G$ such that $gh\neq e$, then $(gh)^2=e$ since $gh\in G$ by closure and so $gh$ has order two.  Then $(ghgh)(h^{-1}g^{-1})=e(h^{-1}g^{-1})\Rightarrow gh=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.  But $h=h^{-1}, g=g^{-1}$, so $$ gh=hg $$ Therefore $G$ is abelian.